# How to retrieve the date of the document with timestamp with Firestore in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i want to retrieve all my documents with a value timestamp but i get all the values without the column timestamp.

```
$json = [];
    $snapshot = $query->documents();
    foreach ($snapshot as $document) {
        if($document->exists())
        {
            $json[] = $document->data();
        }
    }
    return $json;
```

I need to add something else to retrieve documents with timestamp in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not away of the Firestore client dropping data, but may be missing something here. Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of one of your documents from the Firebase console, showing the field with the data? And then please also print the data in your code, and include what is printed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Firestore Timestamp is an object, if you want to display it, you have to convert it into your desire formate like date or string. with the help of following function you will get your snapshot with timestamp value as string.

```
 public function getSnapshot($yourQuery)
{
    $json = [];
    $snapshot = $yourQuery->documents();
    foreach ($snapshot as $document) 
    {
        if($document->exists())
        {
            $d = [];
            foreach($document->data() as $key => $data)
            {
                if(is_object($data))
                {
                    $d[$key] = $data->formatAsString();
                }
                else
                {
                    $d[$key] = $data;
                }
            }
            
            $json[] = $d;
        }
    }
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: Which part of this is returning the timestamp?